# Step by step guide to install Redmine in windows 32-bit (x86)

Tags: redmine, agile-project-management

- Can anyone help me to install Redmine in windows 32-bit pc ? A lot of confusing steps here [Redmine installation link](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall). Request anyone to explain this in a simplified way ?
- Should I go for any other Project Management tool with simpler steps to install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went for the easy way out and used the Bitnami redmine stack. 
This is a installer packaging all dependencies and setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to deploy Redmine, however I would not recommend using 32bit PC anymore.

For enterprise usage if you want to work on MS Platforms from some reason, you can deploy it with Microsoft SQL Server and Internet Information server.

Try following for example:
[Redmine on win2k12](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/49636)